# on click of notification "launching activity" has extras as null, when app is in foreground or back ground in Android api 28 (pie)

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie

Below is my code for pending intent for Android API level greater then 8:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivityBDO.class);
intent.putExtra("requestNotifyData", requestData);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent contentIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

String CHANNEL_ID = chanelID;// The id of the channel.

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    String programId = BankBrandingUtil.getProgramIdForBranding(context);
    Log.d(TAG, "programId: " + programId);
    icon = R.drawable.pn_icon;
    CharSequence name;
    name = "Transactions";// The user-visible name of the channel.
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
    mChannel.setDescription(context.getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_iap_notification_channel_desc));
    getNotificationManager(context).createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),  R.drawable.ic_launcher);

//Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
builder.setTicker(tickerText)
       .setContentTitle(title)
       .setContentText(text);
builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setWhen(when);

Notification notification = builder.build();

notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

Log.v(TAG, "notifiTag: " + notifiTag);
Log.v(TAG, "notifiId: " + notifiId);

getNotificationManager(context).notify(notifiTag, notifiId, notification);
```

In `NotificationActivityBDO` i m getting extras as below:

```
Bundle extras = activity.getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    requestData = (RequestData) extras.getSerializable("requestNotifyData");
}
```

Above code is working fine for below 8 and recently my device got update to pie (Android version 9), notification is rendered and on click I see in launching activity extras as `null`.

Irrespective of app in background or foreground I'm getting  `requestMoneyData` as `null` and when debugging I see extras as "empty parcel" and this happened only in Android version 9 and its working fine in below Android 9.

Any help is appreciated to resolve the above problem.

Comment: Can you paste get intent code of the activity ?

Comment: Bundle extras = activity.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            requestData = (RequestData) extras.getSerializable("requestNotifyData");
        }

Comment: did you try getting the extra's using intent in that activity?

Comment: yes, not working

Comment: in launching activity in oncreate method  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) i m getting savedInstanceState as null

Comment: please try to get the data from onNewIntent Override method.

Comment: activity is single task so onNewIntent logs not getting printed

Answer (score 0):

```
Setting extras with Bundle:
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putSerializable("name", requestList);
 intent.putExtra("notification", bundle);

Getting extras in activity:
intent.extras.getBundle("notification").getSerializable("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use send data

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("here url will be there"))
```

to get data

```
final String fcm_message = intent.data.toString()
```